# C# - Searching Time between 2 DateTime Objects of different days

Tags: c#, datetime, time, between, days

i have a list of "event" objects.

In every event i have "EventStartTime" and "EventEndTime" declared as DateTime objects.

I want to be able to search "events" by time , for example 10:00,
the "event" you see below shows that the festival **starts at 22:00 on Feb 17th**,
and **ends at 15:00 the following day**. i have a couple more like these.

```
    new EventsManager.Event() //3
{
    EventType = EventsManager.EventType.Festival,
    EventName = "Twistival",
    EventPlace = placeList[4],
    EventStartTime =new DateTime(2017,02,17,22,0,0),
    EventEndTime = new DateTime(2017,02,18,15,0,0),
    EventNumberOfParticipants = 8000
},
```

So when i search for event that occur, or still occurring at at 10:00
i should get this event.

any suggestions?

Comment: So you just want to know if the event covers 10 on any day? That is you don't have a specific `DateTime` to check?

Comment: Just a note: Name your object something else.  If you put this in a WinForms app, "Event" is going to get confusing quickly.  Try to avoid using keywords as object names.  Before I ever call my code done, I always peruse a thesaurus first if I discover I've used a keyword as an object name, even if the case is different..  "Activity" might be better for your purposes here.

Comment: @user1895086 thanks for the good tip.

Comment: Would like to point out that i'm a .NET student with little Java, C and C# programming knowledge. i haven't gotten to LINQ yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a specific time of day that you want to determine if the event covers regardless of the date it covers it on then there are 4 cases you need to consider.  First if the dates are more than 1 day apart they cover all times of day.  If the start is before the time of day and the end is after the time of day it will cover the time.  The last two cases require that the end date be on the next day from the start date, then either the start date is before the time of day, or the end date is after the time of day.  Note that this also assumes that the start date is before the end date.

```
var events = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>
{
    // start and end after time of day but on different days
    Tuple.Create(
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 22, 0, 0), 
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 18, 15, 0, 0)),
    // start and end before time of day but on different days 
    Tuple.Create(
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 9, 0, 0), 
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 18, 7, 0, 0)),
    // start before and end after same day 
    Tuple.Create(
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 9, 0, 0), 
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 11, 0, 0)),
    // covers more than 1 day
    Tuple.Create(
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 22, 0, 0), 
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 18, 22, 0, 1)),
    // start after and end before on different days 
    Tuple.Create(
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 22, 0, 0), 
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 18, 10, 0, 0)), 
    // start and end before on same day
    Tuple.Create(
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 7, 0, 0), 
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 8, 0, 0)), 
    // start and end after on same day
    Tuple.Create(
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 11, 0, 0), 
        new DateTime(2017, 02, 17, 12, 0, 0)), 
};

var timeOfDay = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0 ,0);

foreach (var x in events)
{
    if (x.Item2 - x.Item1 > TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
        || (x.Item1.TimeOfDay < timeOfDay && x.Item2.TimeOfDay > timeOfDay)
        || (x.Item1.Date < x.Item2.Date 
            && (x.Item1.TimeOfDay < timeOfDay || x.Item2.TimeOfDay > timeOfDay)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

}
```

Will output

```
(2/17/2017 10:00:00 PM, 2/18/2017 3:00:00 PM)
(2/17/2017 9:00:00 AM, 2/18/2017 7:00:00 AM)
(2/17/2017 9:00:00 AM, 2/17/2017 11:00:00 AM)
(2/17/2017 10:00:00 PM, 2/18/2017 10:00:01 PM)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a

```
List<Event> Events;
```

of your `Event`s. You can create a simple LINQ query to get all events running at a special time with a simple method like

```
private IEnumerable<Event> GetRunningEvents(DateTime time)
{
    return Events.Where(E => E.EventStartTime <= time && E.EventEndTime >= time);
}
```

Dont forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

to your file.

**EDIT:** Without LINQ a possible approach is

```
private List<Event> GetRunningEvents(DateTime time)
{
    List<Event> RunningEvents = new List<Event>();
    foreach(Event E in Events)
    {
        if (E.EventStartTime <= time && E.EventEndTime >= time)
        {
            RunningEvents.Add(E);
        }
    }
    return RunningEvents;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, my solution looked almost identical and I refreshed and there this was lol.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP has a specific `DateTime` to check, just that they want to know if the event is occurring at 10 on any day.

Comment: @juharr yeah, nothing specific. i used 10:00 as an example.

Comment: Is this the query you need @MichaelRoskin ?

Comment: I'm actually an ASP.NET student, we haven't got to LINQ yet, so this is kind of gibberish to me. is there a solution using "basic" c# ?

Comment: I've added a non-LINQ approach - but you will see: The LINQ solution is much mor compact and better to read.

Comment: My friend @Fruchtzwerg ,I couldn't get it to work with my code. Thank you for the time you spent helping me, i used juharrs code with little modifications and it worked. bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Linq Where:

```
var list = new List<Event>();
var searchTime = DateTime.Now;
var result = list.Where(e => e.EventStartTime <= searchTime && searchTime <= e.EventEndTime).ToList();
```